# Trying to add siblings to every node in a binary tree with one child so that all nodes have 2 or zero children. In other words no nodes have 1 child

Tags: prolog

My prolog program is supposed take a binary tree and make a new tree that adds a child to any node that only has one child so that all nodes have 2 or zero children. The binary tree representation being used is along the lines of t(73,t(31,t(5,nil,nil),nil),t(101,t(83,nil,t(97,nil,nil)),nil)). The issue is that it only fixes the nodes that have a missing right child and its not working for nodes that are missing a left node.

```
treeEx(X) :-
    X = t(73,t(31,t(5,nil,nil),nil),t(101,t(83,nil,t(97,nil,nil)),nil)).

singleFill(t(_,nil,nil),_,_):-!.

singleFill(t(Root,nil,Right),V,t(Root,t(V,nil,nil),Right)):- 
    singleFill(Right,V,_).

singleFill(t(Root,Left,nil),V,t(Root,Left,t(V,nil,nil))):-
    singleFill(Left,V,_).

singleFill(t(Root,Left,Right),V,t(Root,LD,RD)):-
   singleFill(Left,V,LD),
   singleFill(Right,V,RD).
```

When using the query treeEx(T),singleFill(T,0,L). it should produce the result:

```
T = t(73, t(31, t(5, nil, nil), nil), t(101, t(83, nil, t(97,
nil, nil)), nil)),
L = t(73, t(31, t(5, nil, nil), t(0, nil, nil)), t(101, t(83,
t(0, nil, nil), t(97, nil, nil)), t(0, nil, nil)))
```

however mine produces:

```
T = t(73, t(31, t(5, nil, nil), nil), t(101, t(83, nil, t(97, nil, 
nil)), nil)),
L = t(73, t(31, t(5, nil, nil), t(0, nil, nil)), t(101, t(83, nil, 
t(97, nil, nil)), t(0, nil, nil))) .
```

The problem is that the node with 83 has one child but its not adding the zero. When I traced it I noticed that it was because there are 2 separate reclusive calls that have 2 different forms of the tree so I think that only the nodes with right children are saving the changes to the new tree. However the changes to the left tree are not

Comment: Without running your code, I'm suspicious of the cut and the preponderance of anonymous variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, right off the bat we have a few weird things about your code:

```
?- singleFill(t(1,nil,nil), 0, Y).
true.
```

It's weird to me that this is true but didn't bind anything on `Y`. This must be the behavior that you noticed. I think it may stem from this:

```
?- singleFill(nil, 0, Y).
false.
```

Namely, your code doesn't handle the base case of the recursion. This is why you seem to need so many cases. Always check your predicates with simple inputs close to the base cases, those are the ones that will help you see the problem. In actuality, you only need three cases:

```
single_fill(nil, New, t(New, nil, nil)).
single_fill(t(V, nil, nil), _, t(V, nil, nil)) :- !.
single_fill(t(V, Left, Right), New, t(V, NewLeft, NewRight)) :-
    single_fill(Left, New, NewLeft),
    single_fill(Right, New, NewRight).
```

Notice that I'm only ignoring one variable here, and it's the fill variable in the case where no filling happens.

I still have a cut here, which I'm not happy about. Without the cut, the first solution matches your specification but you get several more, basically one for each case where there was nil in both branches in the tree. With the cut, this predicate will successfully "check" those inputs even though it wouldn't generate them, which is a violation of backwards correctness. This suggests to me that there may be a better way to write this that doesn't have this problem. But I couldn't think of it. I feel like it should be sufficient to say `Left \= nil, Right \= nil` instead but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks so much this makes so much sense